# Date format of mails sent by Mantis Bug Tracker

Tags: php, mysql, mantis

Im using Mantis bug tracker v1.1.8. When mails sent from mantis arrive in my company inbox,the date shown on the Inbox page is "Unknown Date" for the message.
On opening the message, i can see the actual date. The date of mails received from Mantis is of the format  Thu, 31 Dec 2009 12:30:28 +0580, whereas the date format of other mails is like Mon, 21 Dec 2009 06:56:18 +0100 [12/21/2009 11:26:18 AM IST].

Any way to fix this problem ?
Thank You

Comment: @tim: see my comment in response to your comment.

Answer (score 2):

In the `config_inc.php` Mantis configuration file, you should be able to define your own date format for the "complete date" setting:

```
  / / Setting the language and date format  
  $ g_default_language = 'french';  
  $ g_short_date_format = 'dm-Y';  
  $ g_normal_date_format = 'dmY H: i';  
  $ g_complete_date_format = 'dmY H: i';
```

It should follow the [php date format convention](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). You could then use those format conventions to build the exact date output you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply VonC. I think i have to specify one of those formats in config_inc.php, right ?. But, how to add the following part to the date [12/21/2009 11:26:18 AM IST] ?...Please help. Thanks

Comment: @tim: right. something like `D, j M Y h:i:s O [m/d/Y h:i:s A T]` ought to be defined for the `g_complete_date_format` setting in the `config_inc.php`